# How to rewrite URL to pass params in a RESTful URL style in node.js Express

Tags: node.js, url-rewriting, express

I'm a node.js newbie and finding myself a bit stumped with the following simple requirement:

I want to use a url with the structure:

> /report/34eabc

...where I want this to route to /public/report.html with '34aebc' as a parameter that I can access via client-side Javascript (Bootstrap.js framework).

My server is set up like this:

```
//Create server
var app = express();

// Configure server
app.configure( function() {
    //parses request body and populates request.body
    app.use( express.bodyParser() );
    //checks request.body for HTTP method overrides
    app.use( express.methodOverride() );
    //perform route lookup based on url and HTTP method
    app.use( app.router );
    //Where to serve static content
    app.use( express.static( path.join( application_root, 'public') ) );
    //Show all errors in development
    app.use( express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});


//Start server
var port = 4711;
var server = require('http').createServer(app), io =require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen( port, function() {

    console.log( 'Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', port, app.settings.env );
});

// Routes
app.get( '/api', function( request, response ) {

    response.send( 'API is running' );

});
```

I'd like to be as lightweight on the middleware frameworky stuff as possible, but I sense that I am maybe missing the paradigm I should be using here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use named parameters:

```
app.get( '/report/:id', function(req,res){
    var id = req.params.id;
    // id gets the value '34eabc' (or whatever is passed in in the URL)
    // do your stuff....
});
```

Comment: This may be a stupid question - but how do I pass public/report.html back out? Can I literally use an underscore template and spit out the html? Does that conflict with `app.use( express.static( path.join( application_root, 'public') ) );` Is there a way to tell Express to 'serve this page' and be routed through the same stack as a regular html page?

Comment: You can use `res.sendfile('public/report.html')` for that purpose.  It won't conflict with the static routing, unless there's a static file that matches your URL, and static routing is configured before your `app.get` call.

Comment: No problem...have fun!  I've been really loving Node+Express...it's a really rewarding platform to work on.

Comment: Yeah, the declarative expressiveness for web apps is amazing - time and again something I clunkily expressed in PHP is directly expressable in node.